# Logical solution for creating a JSON structure

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, jakarta-ee

I am not sure if it possible or not but I think it can be done using JSONArray.put method. 
Heres my problem:

I have got two lists:

```
ArrayList<Students> nativeStudents;
ArrayList<transferStudents> transferStudents = nativeStudents.getTransferStudentsList();
```

The JSON that I generate with transferStudents list is right here: http://jsfiddle.net/QLh77/2/ using the following code:

```
  public static JSONObject getMyJSONObject( List<?> list )
    {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        JsonConfig config = new JsonConfig();
        config.addIgnoreFieldAnnotation( MyAppJsonIgnore.class );

        if( list.size() > 0 )
        {
            JSONArray array = JSONArray.fromObject( list, config );

            json.put( "students", array );
        }
        else
        {
            //Empty Array
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
            json.put( "students",
                      array );
        }

        return json;
    }
```

Now what I want to get is JSON data with following structure: http://jsfiddle.net/bsa3k/1/ (Notice the **tempRollNumber** field in both array elements). 
I was thinking of doing: (The if condition here is used for a business logic)

```
if(transferStudents.getNewStudentDetails().getRollNumber() == nativeStudents.getNativeStudentDetails.getStudentId()){

     json.put("tempRollNumber", transferStudents.getNewStudentDetails().getRollNumber());

}
```

but this would add tempRollNumber outsite the array elements, I want this JSON element to be part of every entry of students array.

PS: I cant edit the transferStudents class in order to add tempRollNumber field.

Comment: It's better to create Java objects to represent your objects then use your application server (you must have one because you've tagged this java-ee) generate the JSON for you.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for the suggestion. But this problem is very tied up. I have to add this field after the list is populated and right before it gets passed to the front end.

Comment: Extend the object contained in the `List`, adding the field(s) you require, then marshall your objects instead of the objects you're given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one has come up with anything better I'll turn my comments above into an answer.

The best way to handle this is to create an object model of your data and not create the JSON output yourself.  Your app server or container can handle that for you.

Though you cannot change the objects you receive in the `List` you can extend the object's class to add your own fields.  Those fields would then appear in the JSON when you marshall it.

Comment: Hi Paul, thats one option I have kept on charts. I was wondering if there was any other solution?

Comment: The only other option would be to completely deconstruct the object you've been given and create the JSON by hand (meaning using a library).  You can't have your cake and eat it too, i.e. automatically unmarshal the objects while modifying them, at least not easily.